# Count string by group (R)

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

In annual grouping, I would like to get the number of times a string appears in multiple variables (columns).

```
year <- c("1993", "1994", "1995")
var1 <- c("tardigrades are usually about 0.5 mm long when fully grown.", "slow steppers", "easy") 
var2 <- c("something", "polar bear", "tardigrades are prevalent in mosses and lichens and feed on plant cells")
var3 <- c("kleiner wasserbaer", "newly hatched", "happy learning")
tardigrades <- data.frame(year, var1, var2, var3)
      
      
count_year <- tardigrades %>%
group_by(year) %>%
summarize(count = sum(str_count(tardigrades, 'tardigrades')))
```

Unfortunately, the total sum is added to each year with this solution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should (almost) *never* use the original frame (`tardigrades`) in a dplyr pipe. If you want to operate on most or all columns, then you need to be using some aggregating or iterating function and be explicit about the columns (e.g., `everything()` in tidyselect-speak).

Two suggestions for how to approach this:

1. Pivot and summar

   ```r
   library(dplyr)
   library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
   pivot_longer(tardigrades, -year) %>%
     group_by(year) %>%
     summarize(count = sum(grepl("tardigrades", value)))
   # # A tibble: 3 x 2
   #   year  count
   #   <chr> <int>
   # 1 1993      1
   # 2 1994      0
   # 3 1995      1
   ```
2. Sum across the columns, this must be done `rowwise` (and not by `year`):

   ```r
   tardigrades %>%
     rowwise() %>%
     summarize(
       year,
       count = sum(grepl("tardigrades", c_across(-year)))
       .groups = "drop")
   # # A tibble: 3 x 2
   #   year  count
   #   <chr> <int>
   # 1 1993      1
   # 2 1994      0
   # 3 1995      1
   ```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much - especially the detailed description.